# Implement Search in React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new at react 
I want to implement a Search in react like https://www.trivago.in, 
my Ui contains a search box a dropdown and a submit button,when the submit button is clicked i want to search the data and show that data into result Component, as the same happening in  **Trivago Website**, i don't have any idea how to implement search, can anyone give me some reference code.

I have used react-router-dom to navigate to the result page, when i am clicking the submit button it is navigating me to the result page.
I want to implement Search and send form data to make search based on the text input..

```
import React,{ Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import logo from './case_logo.jpeg';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Result from './Result';
import AdvanceFilter from './AdvanceFilter';

import SearchComponent from './components/SearchComponent';
import Footer from './components/Footer';
class App extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      click: false,
    }
  }

     handleClick() {
        console.log("Sbbmit button clicked");
        this.setState({
            click:true,
        });
    }

render(){
  const { click } = this.state;
  if(click){
    return(
        <Result />
    );

  }

  return (
    <div className="body">
    <div className="h-100">
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-sm-12">
          <center>
          <img src ={ logo } alt="logo" id="logo"/>
          </center>
        </div>
          {/**Search Form*/}
          <div className="col-sm-12">
                <div className="d-flex justify-content-center">
                    <form className="input-group col-sm-8" action="">
                    <input type="search" className="form-control" placeholder="Search"/>

             <div className="drop_down input-group-append">
                 <button className="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" > Dropdown button</button>
                   <div className="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                     <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                     <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                     <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                    </div>
              </div>

               <Link to='/Result'><button type="submit" className="btn btn-secondary" style={{marginLeft: '5px'}} >Search</button></Link>
            </form>

      </div>
     </div>
     {/**End of Search Form*/}

        </div>
        <div className="col-sm-12">
        <Link to='/AdvanceFilter' style={{float:'right', marginRight:'250px', marginTop:'10px '}}>Advance Filter</Link>
        </div>
    </div>
    <Footer />
</div>


  );
}
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Commercial searching is usually done using something like [Solr](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/) Check out this [Solr tutorial](http://www.solrtutorial.com/). You would then use the Solr APIs to make your search